# How to create .Net backend for IOS hub notification without hosting on Azure?

Tags: .net, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

Recently I created a HUB Notification for IOS in Azure, the TEST works good, so now my next step is to create the backend in .NET but Im not sure if [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-windows-dotnet-wns-notification/) tutorial will help me as I dont want to publish my website in Azure. 
In fact, I already have my web app that has other modules and the last I created its going to be used for "breaking news".
Another option will be to create a Windows service in .Net runing on my own server, that will just check the database every x time for news, and send them to the notification hub I have on Azure.
Is there any other tutorial to accomplish this on your own server?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The [Azure Notification Hubs Notify Users with .NET backend](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-windows-dotnet-wns-notification/#publish-the-new-webapi-backend) tutorial you mentioned is what you need. You will just have to do it differently from the [Publish the new WebAPI Backend](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-windows-dotnet-wns-notification/#publish-the-new-webapi-backend) section of it: either select 'Custom' there and see what are non-Azure deployment options are or just skip the section all together, deploy the code in a way that works for you and adapt the rest of the article accordingly in terms of how you connect the client and the server.

The tutorial is just a framework to build on your own and it uses Azure as an example because the person who wrote it chose to use it. You can adapt parts of it to your problem in any way you want.